# SwiftUI pass data up view hierarchy from list

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI application. It has a list of rows, each of which has a constant property saying whether it needs to be on and a property saying whether it is on. This second property is only mutable if the row needs to be on. These rows are sorted; the ones that need to be on are all above the ones that do not. There is also a "Go!" button, that is currently disabled. I want it to be enabled if all of the rows that need to be on are on, but I don't know how to pass data up the view hierarchy. I also don't know Combine yet, so if that's the answer and example would be nice. Thanks!

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    let models = [Model.testCase, .testCase2, .testCase3]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(models.sorted { first, second in
                if first.needsToBeOn { return true }
                if !second.needsToBeOn { return true }
                return false
            }) { model in
                NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                    RowView(model: model)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Models"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {}) {
                Text("Go!").font(.title)
            }.disabled(true))
        }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    let model: Model
    @State var isOn = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Must Be On:")
                Text("\(model.needsToBeOn)")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Picked Up")
                Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
                    Text("")
                }.labelsHidden().disabled(!model.needsToBeOn)
            }
        }.padding(7.5)
    }
}

struct Model: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID

    let needsToBeOn: Bool

    static let testCase = Model(id: UUID(), needsToBeOn: true)
    static let testCase2 = Model(id: UUID(), needsToBeOn: true)
    static let testCase3 = Model(id: UUID(), needsToBeOn: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have chance to test but try below code

```
struct ListView: View {
@State private var models = [Model.testCase, .testCase2, .testCase3]
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(models.sorted { first, second in
            if first.needsToBeOn { return true }
            if !second.needsToBeOn { return true }
            return false
        }) { model in
            NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                RowView(model: self.$model)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Models"))
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Go!").font(.title)
        }.disabled(true))
    }
   }
 }



struct RowView: View {
@Binding var model: Model
@State var isOn = false
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack {
            Text("Must Be On:")
            Text("\(model.needsToBeOn)")
        }
        Spacer()
        VStack {
            Text("Picked Up")
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
                Text("")
                model.needsToBeOn = self.isOn
            }.labelsHidden().disabled(!model.needsToBeOn)
        }
    }.padding(7.5)
}
```

}

Comment: The line `RowView(model: self.$model)` didn't work because `model` isn't a `@State` variable, so I changed it to `self.$models[self.models.firstIndex(of: model)!]`

Comment: If there's a better way to do this, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working.

```
struct ListView: View {
    @State var models = [Model.testCase0, .testCase1, .testCase2, .testCase3]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(models.enumerated().sorted { first, second in
                first.element.needsToBeOn ? true : !second.element.needsToBeOn
            }, id: \.element.id) { e in
                NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                    RowView(model: self.$models[e.offset])
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Models"))
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                Button(action: {
                    self.models.append(Model(needsToBeOn: true))
                    print(self.models.map{$0.needsToBeOn})
                }) {
                    Text("Add")
                },
                trailing: Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Go!").font(.title)
                    // optionally we filter to take only obligatory switches into account
                }.disabled(!(models.filter({ $0.needsToBeOn}).reduce(true, { (r, m) in
                    r && m.needsToBeOn == m.isActuallyOn
                }))))
        }
    }
}



struct RowView: View {
    @Binding var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Must Be On:")
                Text("\(model.needsToBeOn.description)")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Picked Up")
                Toggle(isOn: $model.isActuallyOn) {
                    Text("")
                }.labelsHidden().disabled(!model.needsToBeOn)
            }
        }.padding(7.5)
    }
}

struct Model: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var needsToBeOn: Bool
    var isActuallyOn: Bool = false

    static let testCase0 = Model(needsToBeOn: false) // to check the sorting
    static let testCase1 = Model(needsToBeOn: true)
    static let testCase2 = Model(needsToBeOn: true)
    static let testCase3 = Model(needsToBeOn: false)
}
```